# How to disable camera in amazon chime sdk meeting

Tags: reactjs, amazon-chime

I'm creating a meeting using amazon chime sdk library (in reactjs), where I don't want the option to open the camera at all. When the meeting is created, I'm setting the video input to null:

```
meetingManager.meetingSession.audioVideo.chooseVideoInputDevice(null)
```

What is happening is that the browser is asking for permissions to use the camera, turn it on for a second, and then turn it off (when the chooseVideoInputDevice() is being called).

What I want is to never ask for the camera permission, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try join meeting with `DeviceLabels.None` to achieve your goal.

```js
import {
  DeviceLabels,
  useMeetingManager,
} from 'amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react';

const meetingManager = useMeetingManager();

await meetingManager.join({
  meetingInfo,
  attendeeInfo,
  deviceLabels: DeviceLabels.None, // here
});
```